# How to autofocus an image on a webpage?

Tags: html, angular

I want autofocus on my image when the page loads. Tabindex is not working for me. 
As I have a different angular2 header component with Menus which also has tabindexes defined and always takes precedence. When the page loads, I want my image to be autofocused irrespective of the tab index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img href="..." #img (load)="img.focus()" tabindex="0">
```

Comment: Is there a way to focus on a specific image if we are running through images in ngFor and only want the first image to be focused?

Comment: <div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let image of productDetails?.ImageAttachments;let i = index" >
<img  #img{{i}} (load)="img0.focus();"  tabindex="0" aria-label="View product image on mouse over" />
 </div>

Comment: I tried changing it to  #img{{i}}  and (load)="img0.focus()"  but this doesnt work

Comment: That's not supposed to work. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: there are dynamic number of images that come from back-end and I want the first image to be focused on page load.

Comment: Tried this also but it doesnt work either:
 <img  #img  *ngIf="i==0?img.focus()"

Comment: no idea what that is supposed to do. You can try to wrap the img tag with `<ng-container *ngIf="i==0">...<ng-container>`. If it doesn't work, please add more information to your question what you try to accomplish.